# Android/java cut all <pre>asdf</pre> from xml

Tags: android, string

How can i do that, from a simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load your xml and have it as a string (or any other object that supports working with regex) you can use pattern:

`<pre>(.+?)</pre>`

For example:

`String mString = "Hello, let's strip <pre>some</pre> tags";`


`mString = mString.replaceAll("<pre>(.+?)</pre>", "");`

mString will be == "Hello, let's strip tags" after this operation;

P.S. Since I'm lame at escaping tags here, remove all the problems I left in pattern :)

Comment: I'll just leave this here... ;)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454